# Simple array push in PHP exceeds allowed memory. (Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 33554440 bytes) )

Tags: php, memory-management, memory-leaks

This code is part of a bigger program but I identified this as the problem. I simply need to get the same values at the same indexes of arrays and this is the code I have written:

```
$a1=array(1,1,2);
$a2=array(1,2);
$a3=array(1,1);
$a4=array(1,1,3);
$a5=array(1,1,1,1);

$same= array();
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
    while($a1[$i]==$a2[$i] && $a1[$i]==$a3[$i] && $a1[$i]==$a4[$i] && $a1[$i]==$a5[$i]){
        array_push($same, $a1[$i]);
    }
}
print_r($same);
```

and it gives me this error:

> Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 33554440 bytes)

Adding more memory here is not an option.

Comment: Can you please give a _proper_ explanation of what you actually need to achieve here? I can not tell from your description, and the code does not make enough sense to me either, to be able to tell from that. `while($a1[$i]=$a2[$i]=$a3[$i])` – those are _assigments_, so the value of that expression will always be that of `$a3[$i]` – are you sure that’s what you actually meant to begin with?

Comment: I'd like to get the same values of the same keys from 5 different arrays. I already used the "==" to check for equality and compare them like this 
`$a1[$i]==$a2[$i] && $a1[$i]==$a3[$i] && $a1[$i]==$a4[$i] && $a1[$i]==$a5[$i]`
in my while loop but it still gives me the error.

Comment: _“I'd like to get the same values of the same keys from 5 different arrays.”_ - still unclear what exactly that is supposed to mean. Please go read [ask], and then please give us a _proper_ explanation - including sample input data, and what exact result you expect to get based on that.

Comment: With the arrays given in the post, the following loops are supposed to output the values which have the same key. So with these arrays the `$same` array can now only contain just one value. `[0] => 1` because the `$a2` array already has a different number in the next positions than the rest of them.

Comment: Still not entirely clear to me, what you actually want. Why is the for loop going to `$i<3`, where does that magic number come from? And why is there even a second loop inside the for? Perhaps that `while` should be a simple `if` instead? Then this could _start_ to make some sense …

Comment: That while should have been an if, and that was the main mistake why the error was showing and that's what I was looking to get helped for. The 3 was just a placeholder, forgive me for not explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you while loop runs infinitely

`while($a1[$i]=$a2[$i]=$a3[$i]){`

You see the equal sign? You just assign one value to another from right to left. If you want to check if all of them are equal you can do:

`while($a1[$i] == $a2[$i] && $a1[$i] == $a3[$i] && $a2[$i] == $a3[$i]){`

Overall, I think the code can & should be improved. You should not limit your `for loop` to a hardcoded number. Rather, limit it to the smallest array length. There are many ways to fix this issue.

Edit:

Your while loop runs infinitely because when index **$i** is zero, all values are equal and it gets stuck in the while loop. Replace the **while loop** with **if**. This will solve the **memory size error**, but you should also check if the **keys** exist before comparing them.

Comment: There are actually 5 arrays that I need to compare, I thought simplifying it here might help but it didn't.  I compare them like this in my while loop: 
`$a1[$i]==$a2[$i] && $a1[$i]==$a3[$i] && $a1[$i]==$a4[$i] && $a1[$i]==$a5[$i]`
but it still gives the same error when pushing those values in a different array.

Comment: I see. BTW you are pushing values to one array, and then printing an empty one. is this intentional?

Comment: Forgot to change that one, variables are written in a different language.

Comment: If possible, please update your question with the original code. Because right now the infinite loop is caused by an assignment operation inside the while loop

Comment: Code updated with arrays as in original code!

Comment: Ok. I see the problem. Let's start from the beginning. we enter the `for loop`. the value pf `$i` is 0. Correct? We enter the while loop. it is true. We check again. it is true again. And so on. the value of **$i** never changes. replace while loop with if statement and you will not have the memory size error again. However, you will have an error that says the **$a2**, for example, doesn't have key *2*

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Any way to hide those errors from the output?

Comment: I would recommend fixing the logic of the code so that it doesn't throw any errors or warnings. IMO it wouldn't be wise to ignore them. First, remove the hardcoded limit of the for loop with `count($a1)`. Next, check if the key exists of any array other than **$a1** before performing any operation with them. Such as comparing them, for example